# Reading tiff Image from Oracle long raw by c# not working

Tags: c#, oracle, oracleforms

I have a long raw column contains a tiff image which is saved by oracle form application, I'm trying to retrieve the image by c# and save it with no luck, the image is valid, but it display crappy drawing.

DataBase column definition

```
SIGNATURE     NOT NULL LONG RAW()
```

C# Code

internal void save(string account)
        {
            var commonAccount = new List();

```
        using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["-----"].ConnectionString))
        {
            var imgCmd = new OracleCommand("select SIGNATURE, number, code, name  from table_name where number = ***** and code = *****", cn);
            imgCmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1;
            cn.Open();

            var reader = imgCmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                //var v1 = reader[0];
                var v2 = reader[1].ToString();
                var v3 = reader[2].ToString();
                var v4 = reader[3].ToString();

                OracleBinary imgBinary = reader.GetOracleBinary(0);

                // Get the bytes from the binary obj
                byte[] imgBytes = imgBinary.IsNull ? null : imgBinary.Value;

                var newData = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);


                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                stream.Write(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length);
                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(stream);
                bm.Save("d:\\image.tif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
```

The saved image looks like
[image: Saved image by c#]

I built new oracle form and bound the image with the column, and it displayed correctly, any idea?
[image: By Oracle form]

EDIT:
I found that the image in Oracle database saved as Big-Endian byte order

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error. Here's what I did: 1) created a table with a single field; 2) inserted a single row with an image data; 2) created [this program](https://gist.github.com/defaultlocale/1877bad08ee71f5b2a97b3eaf026ba5f) based on your code. The code worked perfectly, the correct image was saved in `D:\image.tiff`. What am I doing wrong? Can you help me to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Your example consists of two parts: 1) database access; 2) byte array manipulation. Perhaps, you can determine which one of them is problematic. To do this you'll need to compare the content of `imgBytes` with the actual bytes in the database. If byte values don't match you'll be able to remove the bitmap manipulation and concentrate on the database access (an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help.)

Comment: Have you saved the image to oracle through oracle form? or from the .net side, I'm not sure if oracle form Image component do some magic to the picture when saving it to the database, like compression?

Comment: No, I just inserted the image directly into the database with SQLDeveloper. Then I was able to verify that the C# code works properly. Not sure about Oracle Forms, it makes sense to check what is actually stored in the database.

Comment: Insert this text into long raw column

Comment: Yes, I actually inserted a TIFF image file into the long raw column. It worked.

Comment: How you inserted it?

Comment: There're many different ways, PLSQL Developer is able to upload the image directly from the GUI. SQLDeveloper should be able to do the same: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-quick-tip-blobs-and-images/

Comment: Check this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44hVrrB2_nQ
on minute 8:30, same result i have in my database, starting with 4D4D002A

Comment: After doing some troubleshooting it seems the image saved as tiff OJPEG compression, any idea how to convert it in c# to normal tiff? of jpeg?

Comment: Sorry, have no idea. Have you tried to store the bytes directly, e.g. `File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\image.tiff", imgBytes);`?

Comment: Another found, The data saved in oracle as big-endian since the server is Solaries, and when trying to read it in windows it's show corrupted image, because windows understand little-endian

Comment: That's interesting. You should publish your findings in the question itself. As well as an example of a tiff file.

Answer (score 1):

After few days of understanding and finding solutions around, the following solved my problem, the code below convert to another type of image encoding also do converting to little-endian

Please note that, the code is using [BitMiracle.LibTiff](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) library,

```
        private string GetBase64Data(byte [] image)
    {
        var data = string.Empty;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image))
        {
            using (Tiff tif = Tiff.ClientOpen("in-memory", "r", ms, new TiffStream()))
            {
                // Find the width and height of the image
                FieldValue[] value = tif.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH);
                int width = value[0].ToInt();

                value = tif.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH);
                int height = value[0].ToInt();

                // Read the image into the memory buffer
                int[] raster = new int[height * width];
                if (!tif.ReadRGBAImage(width, height, raster))
                {
                    return data;
                }

                using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

                    BitmapData bmpdata = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                    byte[] bits = new byte[bmpdata.Stride * bmpdata.Height];

                    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                    {
                        int rasterOffset = y * bmp.Width;
                        int bitsOffset = (bmp.Height - y - 1) * bmpdata.Stride;

                        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
                        {
                            int rgba = raster[rasterOffset++];
                            bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)((rgba >> 16) & 0xff);
                            bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)((rgba >> 8) & 0xff);
                            bits[bitsOffset++] = (byte)(rgba & 0xff);
                        }
                    }

                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bits, 0, bmpdata.Scan0, bits.Length);
                    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpdata);

                    MemoryStream ims = new MemoryStream();
                    bmp.Save(ims, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    data = Convert.ToBase64String(ims.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```